# How to implement Shortcut Keys in Sapper?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, svelte, sapper

As far as what I have tried..

```
<script>
import {goto} from '@sapper/app'

function shortcut(event) {
   if (event.altKey && event.keyCode == 73) {
      goto('/istifta')
   }
}
</script>
<svelte:window on:keyup={shortcut}/>
```

The code is inside `_layout.svelte`. The code works fine but after some attempts it stops working. I don't know why.

Comment: This sounds like something we'd need a repro for

Comment: https://svelte.dev/examples#svelte-window